# Manage multiple wordpress installs (Best Practice)

Tags: publish, xml-rpc, management

Our company has multiple blogging platforms on which some of our people post on.

The list of platforms keeps on growing and so keeping everything up to date can be rather bothersome.

So we were thinking of creating a platform/dashboard where we could manage our blogs and publish new posts from one location.

Now I have tried and tested some tools already (wpremote, managewp, mainwp)
But, while some of them work great, we would like to be able to create this ourselves and maintain it ourselves.

My main question is. What would be a good practice.
MainWP for example is free and open source but uses iframes to publish to different blogs while the others use the XML-RPC functionality to maintain other blogs.

Of course in the future we would want to d more with this tool but linking blogs would be the first step. (Think of SEO optimization, social networking options etc)

p.s. I have had some answers on other channels saying I could go for a Multisite but adding wp installs that need their own domain instead of a subdomain seems to be quite the hassle

Answer (score 0):

MainWP does not use iframes to publish posts it uses the "newpost" function for the Dashboard to send the new post to your child site.

You can see the newpost function in action with these GitHub searches:

[newpost on Dashboard](https://github.com/mainwp/mainwp/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=newpost)

[newpost on Child](https://github.com/mainwp/mainwp-child/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=newpost)

If you need custom processes built you can check the MainWP Codex for functions and tutorials

Comment: interesting. I was under the impression it was a iframe. But obviously that function just returns the "add post" window into a iframe (see image)

[MainWP](http://i.imgur.com/liRHkcn.png)


Which is fine. Seeing as I haven't done a XML-RPC version yet is this anything different?


Does what MainWP does anything different then what a XML-RPC connection does?


Thanks for the answer!